# Extension Library in Domino: Server or Client? Or both?

Tags: client, server, lotus-domino

this may seem like a dumb question but im not that long into Notes/Domino.
I want to run Extension Library by openNTF. Now the question is, if i develop an application with it, can the application itself be used by other clients eventough they dont have the Ext. Lib. installed?
And when i say used i mean USED, not edited. And if not, do they need Ext.Lib.(client) too or can i just install it on the Server? Or do i have to install it on both?

Sorry for the bad english.
Thanks if you can answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using one of the OSGI Plug-ins (the Extension Library is one such plugins) means that the machine running the code will need to have that plug-in already installed.

[This is an excellent first step from Stephan Wissel](http://www.wissel.net/blog/d6plinks/SHWL-8GZM9A)

You are going to need to set up an updatesite for your server in any case. If your users are using the Xpages application using the browser they won't need to install anything, if you are counting in using XPinc (XPages in Notes Client), then the library will need to be pushed to the user's local machines as well, typically with a widget catalog.

Comment: hmm kinda expected that. sucks. well thanks a lot tho.